# Fiddler-Auditor: No module named 'auditor' error, however this module is in my project folder

Tags: python, import, module

I try to access auditor folder from another folder like this

```
from auditor.evaluation.expected_behavior import SimilarGeneration
```

[Project Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSqPZ.png)

However, I get this error "No module named 'auditor'"

I tried many ways like:

```
from ..auditor.evaluation.expected_behavior import SimilarGeneration
```

or

```
from .auditor.evaluation.expected_behavior import SimilarGeneration
```

and I also tried to add a sys path in order ro access this module. However, none of them worked for me.

I use Visual Studio Code as an IDE.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your folder to sys.path. Add this code at start of your file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(“.”) #if it doesn’t work, replace “.” by the auditor’s folder
import auditor
```

Comment: It does not work :(

Comment: Did you replace “.” by your auditor’s folder ? What generates an error, my code or the yours?

Comment: Yes, I replaced dot with auditor's folder path. But it still says "import auditor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'auditor'" on the import auditor line.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't know how to resolve, you can check [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/module-not-found-error-in-python-solved/) or [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-and-importerror-248ce5b69b1c) to resolve, or reinstall fiddler-auditor: `pip install --upgrade fiddler-auditor`

Answer (score 0):

My supervisor solved this issue like that:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../fiddler-auditor-main")
```

I do not know why but it works with this path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).